# Androidアプリで自分の位置情報を地図に反映したい

Tags: android, java, gps

acitivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
Location currentLocation;
LocationManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Manager");
        builder.setMessage("位置情報をONにしますか？");

        builder.setPositiveButton("はい", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
                moveToYourLocation();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("いいえ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    } else {
        moveToYourLocation();
    }
}

protected void moveToYourLocation(){
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng((float)currentLocation.getLatitude(), (float)currentLocation.getLongitude()), 13);
    map.moveCamera(cu);
}
```

GPS機能がONになっていない場合はダイアログを表示して、ONにするように促します。 
OFFの場合はアプリを終了させます。 
ONになった後に自分の位置情報をマップに反映させ表示したいのですが、問題が発生したとされ強制終了されます。 
moveToYourLocation()がnullだと表示されるのですが、失敗する原因が良く分かりません。 
どこが間違っているのでしょうか？ 
currentLocationにmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);を代入するなど試しましたが失敗しました。

----エラーログです---- 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference 
            at com.examples.mymapactivity.MainActivity.moveToYorLocation(MainActivity.java:65) 
            at com.examples.mymapactivity.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:48) 
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:160) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

Comment: 変数`currentLocation`に現在位置を代入する文がどこにも無いように見えます

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onLocationChangedなどを使い、currentLocationに代入するのを忘れていました。